# Core Dumps When Trying to Load Audio in Processing IDE

Tags: javascript, java, processing

I'm trying to create a program inside Processing IDE (3.1.2), which will have background audio. Here's the code so far;

```
    import processing.sound.*;

    SoundFile file;
    String audioName = "CantinaSong.mp3";
    String path;

    Star[] stars = new Star [1500];

    void setup() {
      size(1000, 1000);
      for (int i = 0; i<stars.length;i++){
        stars [i] = new Star();
      }
    }

    void draw() {
      path = sketchPath (audioName);
      file = new SoundFile(this, path);
      file.play();

      background (0);
      translate(width/2, height/2);
      for (int i = 0; i< stars.length;i++){
        stars [i].update();
        stars [i].show();
      }
    }
```

The file audio file is in the same directory as the Sketch, but when I try to run the program I get the following error;

```
    #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  Internal Error (0x20474343), pid=5212, tid=0x0000000000001264
    #
    # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_102-b14) (build 1.8.0_102-b14)
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.102-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Problematic frame:
    # C  [KERNELBASE.dll+0x1a06d]
    #
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # An error report file with more information is saved as:
    # C:\Users\jrr7e\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid5212.log
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    # The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
    # See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
    #
    Could not run the sketch (Target VM failed to initialize).
    For more information, read revisions.txt and Help ? Troubleshooting
```

I've tested this across multiple OS and still run across the same core dump. 
I've seen plenty of people having problems with this online, but no solutions yet.

Is there any way to stop the Core dump from happening in Processing? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
Here's the class Star as well, if anyone is interested in the visual portion of it.

```
    class Star {
      float x;
      float y;
      float z;

      float px;
      float py;

      Star(){
        x = random(-width, width);
        y = random (-height, height);
        z = random(width);
      }

      void update(){
        z -= 100;
        if (z < 1){
          x = random(-width, width);
          y = random (-height, height);
          z = width; 
          px=x;
          py=y;
        }
      }
      void show(){
        fill(255);
        noStroke();
        float sx = map (x/z, 0, 1, 0, width);
        float sy = map (y/z, 0, 1, 0, height);

        float r = map(z, 0, width, 16, 0);
        ellipse(sx,sy,r,r);

        stroke(255);
        line(px,py,sx,sy);
        px = x;
        py = y;
      }
    }
```

(Note: Some of this code is borrowed from The Coding Train)

EDIT; 
Following Kevin Workman's advice, here's an MCVE of the problematic bit of code, with some editing from the previous.

```
        import processing.sound.*;

        SoundFile file;


        void setup() {
          file = new SoundFile(this, "CantinaSong.mp3");
          file.play();
        }
```

Here is a link to the Sound Audio Library as well. 
https://processing.org/reference/libraries/sound/SoundFile.html

Comment: I forgot to mention; the problem code is based off the Sound library for Processing by The Processing Foundation. If anyone has an alternative library for audio, that would also be a great.

Comment: What happens if you try a different sound file? Is the sound file you're trying to use abnormally short or long? What happens if you try a different computer? Your MCVE looks like it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second. Then inside the `draw()` function, you do this:

```
file = new SoundFile(this, path);
file.play();
```

That means you're loading the same file and playing it 60 times per second. This is certainly one way to blow your computer up.

To fix the problem, you need to modify your code so you only load the sound once (that's what the `setup()` function is for), and only play it when it should be triggered (maybe also in the `setup()` function, but definitely not 60 times per second).

If you're still having trouble, please narrow your problem down to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), like this:

```
import processing.sound.*;

SoundFile file;
String audioName = "CantinaSong.mp3";
String path;

void draw() {
  path = sketchPath (audioName);
  file = new SoundFile(this, path);
  file.play();
}
```

Comment: It still core-dumping, unfortunately. I'll take your advice and edit for a MCVE. Thanks for helping!